# NSMutableData convert to NSString

Tags: iphone

Why data not similar with `objNSData`?

```
NSString *strData = @"Bonjour tout le monde, je voudrais vous présenter la Société fdfdfdf  Futur";
NSMutableData *objNSData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

objNSData = [objNSData EncryptAES:@"samplekey"];

 NSLog(@"objNSData%@", objNSData);

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData: objNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"str%@",str);

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[ str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSLog(@"data%@",data);
```

Comment: [Session started at 2011-07-01 07:39:45 +0100.]
2011-07-01 07:39:47.351 XMLTest[836:207] objNSData<0f6722e2 04d7b6e5 d66e1c1e 403f0364 6e0a362f e54d0aef 01045e38 c0f392a0 58f057cb adbbac6a 2529217e fddaa84c 82a0736d dda5d3bc 45562080 dccb1758 ad497676 0a6e8a48 8fcebcff 1126e38f>
2011-07-01 07:39:47.353 XMLTest[836:207] str(null)
2011-07-01 07:39:47.354 XMLTest[836:207] data<>

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be storing the `NSData` representation of the string, then encrypting it and hoping that converting it back will give you the same thing you started out with.

While I'm not entirely sure why you're trying to encrypt your `NSData` instance, if you want to convert it back into an `NSString` then you most definitely want to decrypt it on the way back.

Comment: because i want save str in xml file and after i want décrypte ther. i have solution that i will use NSISOLatin1StringEncoding but the problem that i can't saved in xml file